# Rails devise gem and user groups

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using rails devise gem for users authentification, but now for my shop i must introduce user groups for discont's, special prices, etc. How to do this with devise? Note that this is one/many-to-many, becouse every user can have many groups, and every group some users.

Also when user is registering i't group must be for example 1.

Devise has "closed" controller (not as in authlogic). That is trouble also.

```
def create
    super
    group = Group.find_by_name("newuser")
    user_group = UserGroup.create
    user_group.user_id = current_user.id
    user_group.group_id = group.group_id
    user_group.save
  end
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This doesn't necessarily have to be integrated with Devise unless I'm reading your question wrong. Just create a Group model describing the attributes of a group, and a UserGroup join model:

```
class UserGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_groups
  has_many :groups, :through => :user_groups

  # attr_accessible :user_id, :group_id
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_groups
  has_many :users, :through => :user_groups
end
```

As for the closed controller problem, you can lift the Devise controller into your application, or create a new controller which inherits from it and thus override the methods. Read more from their [link GitHub page here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers).

**Edit:** I think you are approaching this from the wrong angle. You needn't do anything from within Devise's controllers, but rather add a `before_save` callback to your User model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save(:on => :create) :assign_default_group

  # Other model stuff here

  private

  def assign_default_group
    # This automatically creates the UserGroup record
    self.groups << Group.find_by_name("User")
  end
end
```

Comment: but how then write the same devise sign up logic in my controller?

Comment: @PavelBY If you override the sign up action, you can still call it by `super` from within the overriding action. This is true for all overridable methods in Rails. What do you want to alter in the action? I think that can be done better in an other way.

Comment: But how then do in other way?

Comment: Simple: i need so that devise work as before, but introduce usergroups, so that when somebody register, it for example give it group newcustomer

Comment: @PavelBY Do you still need the many-to-many relationship? Following my example you can ignore the Devise controllers, and to the User model add a `before_save :assign_default_group`, then just define the `assign_default_group` method to add what group the user should belong to by default.

Comment: i have written such part of ovveriden method: but how to get this user id? (added below)

Comment: Also, why do  before_save(:on => :create) :assign_default_group throwing error  syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end, but before_save :assign_default_group  works good?